# How to force calculation of Roll-Up Summary on "clone with Related"/"deepClone" action

Tags: roll-up-summary, clone, lightning-action

We have a Roll-Up Summary field. It's a SUM aggregation of a field on custom childs of Opportunity. The field is set to "Automatic calculation (Recommended)". It usually works fine. For example if we Clone or create an Opportunity the field is correctly calculated to 0.

However when we "Clone with Related" the Summary field is left blank. Where is the difference in the inner workings of Salesforce when using the deepclone action?

Is there a way to force the recalculation other than adding a dummy child and removing it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for specific cases, where you need that "0" in any place with the SF Formula editor available:

BLANKVALUE(*fieldName*, *Replace value*) is a standard SF function. It checks for blank and replaces the blank value with whatever is specified as the 2nd argument, without having to alter the actual value in the field. Just a clean and compact way to check for both 0 and blank. In this case use

```
BLANKVALUE(SummaryField__c, 0)
```